# Unicorn Worker Killer is not reducing memory usage

Tags: ruby, unicorn, sidekiq

I've been struggling with memory issues with my Rails app for the past few days.

I setup a Unicorn server with the sidekiq gem to run background jobs. The jobs were constantly failing in production, so I installed NewRelic to view the memory use, and it showed that the Sidekiq worker was exceeding Heroku's memory limits.

I am now trying to use the unicorn-worker-killer gem to reduce the memory of the worker as the jobs run, but I have not had any success. The logs show this message happening every time I load a page, but it doesn't reduce the memory load.

```
[2014-12-08T13:52:34.346557 #88418]  WARN -- : #<Unicorn::HttpServer:0x00000101025ee8>: worker    (pid: 88418) exceeds memory limit (123482112 bytes > 105673916 bytes)
W, [2014-12-08T13:52:34.346793 #88418]  WARN -- : Unicorn::WorkerKiller send SIGQUIT (pid: 88418) alive: 4 sec (trial 1)
I, [2014-12-08T13:52:34.492893 #88410]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 88418 exit 0> worker=0
I, [2014-12-08T13:52:34.501168 #88441]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
```

Which looks right to me, but the memory taken up by the worker does not go down at all. NewRelic still shows the memory consumption going from 100MB to over 1GB and staying high, without coming down until I restart the server.

Any advice would be tremendously appreciated! I really need my workers to run within memory limits.

Here is my config.ru file:

```
require 'unicorn/oob_gc'
use Unicorn::OobGC, 10 # Only GC once every GC_FREQUENCY requests

# --- Start of unicorn worker killer code ---

require 'unicorn/worker_killer'

max_request_min =  500
max_request_max =  600

# Max requests per worker
use Unicorn::WorkerKiller::MaxRequests, max_request_min, max_request_max

oom_min = (100) * (1024**2)
oom_max = (150) * (1024**2)

# Max memory size (RSS) per worker
use Unicorn::WorkerKiller::Oom, oom_min, oom_max, 1, true

# --- End of unicorn worker killer code ---



# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.

require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
run Rails.application
```

And here is the Unicorn.rb file:

```
worker_processes Integer(1)
timeout 30
preload_app true
stderr_path "log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "log/unicorn.stdout.log"

before_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  end

  old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
  if old_pid != server.pid
    begin
      sig = (worker.nr + 1) >= server.worker_processes ? :QUIT : :TTOU
      Process.kill(sig, File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
    end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env] ||
            Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['reaping_frequency'] = 10 #seconds
    config['pool']            =   ENV['DB_POOL']
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Unicorn has nothing to do with Sidekiq and will not affect its memory usage.  Unicorn handles web requests, Sidekiq handles background jobs.  They are two different processes.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mike. I'm new to all of this, so I may be totally off base, but doesn't the Unicorn worker execute the sidekiq jobs? I've been able to solve my problem mostly by reducing memory leaks for the sidekiq jobs, but it would still be nice to be able to kill the Unicorn worker if it starts to exceed certain memory limits.

Comment: No, Sidekiq runs as a separate process.  The Unicorn process typically creates jobs and sends them to Redis (this is what the perform_async method does).  Sidekiq process pulls the jobs from Redis and executes them.